# Four non-collinear points $A,A',B,B'$ forming a projective basis imply a projective transformation $f$ with $f^2 = I_d$ and $f(A)= A'$, $f(B)= B'$.

Tags: projective-geometry, transformational-geometry

Consider four non-collinear points $A,A',B,B'$ in the projective space $\mathbb{R}P^2$. I want to show that the points $A,A',B,B'$ form a projective basis if and only if there exists a projective transformation $f$ with the properties: $f^2 = I_d$ and $f(A)= A'$, $f(B)= B'$.

I was thinking about looking for a specific form for $f$, but this became to difficult. So I took for the four points the standard projective basis $A = [(1,0,0)]$, $A' = [(0,1,0)]$, $B = [(0,0,1)]$ and $B' = [(1,1,1)]$. In this case, the $f$ with the properties would have the matrix form:
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}

So we proved it here in the case of the standard projective basis and because you can always find a projective transformation between the standard basis and another basis, the statement must hold for every projective basis. But I think there should be a rigorous way of proving this.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456744/assumption-about-the-points-of-the-real-projective-plane) is helpful, too.